# Am trying to check if the student ClassID and the Class_Schedule ClassID match

Tags: c#, sql, .net, model-view-controller

```cs
var sched = db.Class_Schedule.Select(p=>p.ClassID);

var classStudents = db.Students.Where(p => p.Enrollments.Select(q=>q.ClassID).Equals(sched));
return View(classStudents.ToList());
```

I am trying to check the `ClassID` of the student through the enrollment table and see if it matches with the `ClassID` of the `Class_Schedule` table.

This is the exception I am getting:

> 'System.NotSupportedException: 'Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.''

Comment: It is similar to TSQL syntax. You want to use `Where` to filter and `Select` to actually specify what you want to retrieve if it differs from the entity type. You can also use `Join` to join across tables. As far as what it is you are actually trying to do I am not sure because you mention `Student` (singular) but there is no student id or student instance you are using in your statements.

Answer (score 1):

`sched` in your example is of type `IEnumerable<string>`, and the result of `p.Enrollments.Select(q=>q.ClassID)` is too. However, `.Equals()` can only compare, as your error states, primitive types (string, int, etc) but you're calling it on an `IEnumerable` with an `IEnumerable` argument so it fails.

What you want to do, is search through Students where they have `Any` enrollment that's in their schedule. So instead try

```
var classStudents = db.Students.Where(s => s.Enrollments.Any(e => sched.Contains(e.ClassID)));
```

Comment: cannot compare type int with bool

Comment: Can you elaborate? Where does the error occur? What are the types of the `Enrollemnts` and `Class_Schedule` arrays?

Answer (score 0):

use the `Intersect`

```cs
var sched = db.Class_Schedule.Select(p => p.ClassID).ToList();
var classStudents = db.Students.Where(p => p.Enrollments.Select(q=>q.ClassID).ToList().Intersect(sched).Any());
```

Comment: the intersect method does't work i get the error, ' list doesn't contain definition for intersect()

Comment: add `System.Linq;` namespace